# How to remove fee from order

Tags: commerce, rules

I have added a fee with rules using commerce_fee module.
I need to remove the fee but i can´t find a way.
How can this be done?

Comment: I assume you mean the [commerce_fees](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees) module?

Comment: Yes, right, this is the module i use.

Answer (score 0):

Commerce Fees creates a line item of a particular type. You can loop through each of the line items on an order and remove the line item that has a particular type by looking at it's type value. I believe you can remove it by setting the quantity of the line item to 0.